# Acessing SQL database using shiny with reactive query

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I want to use Shiny to let a user build a data frame by accessing an SQL data base. I want it to work in the following way (but open to suggestions):

- User types in ID (its a number)
- User presses action button
- Reactive query is generated
- Query is sent and data is retrieved, and added to data frame
- User types in next ID...

Here is my attempt:

UI

```
library(markdown)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Generic grapher"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

  numericInput("wafer", label = h3("Select wafer ID:"), value = NULL),

  actionButton("do", "An action button")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("value"), verbatimTextOutput("que"), dataTableOutput(outputId="pos")
  )
)))
```

Server

```
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
library(sqldf)

con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname="Test_DB", username="pete", password="xx", host="xx", port=3306)
query <-  function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...) 

wq = data.frame()
df = data.frame()

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

  output$value <- renderPrint({ d() }) 

  a <- reactive({ paste("Select id from wafer where wafer_id=",d(), sep="") })

  output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 

  wq <- reactive({ rbind(wq, query( a() )) })

  output$pos <- renderDataTable({ wq() })
  })
```

When I run, I can see that both the Id and query will print correctly. However I get this error when app firsts runs:

```
error in evaluating the argument 'statement' in selecting a method for function 'dbGetQuery': Error:
```

Then when I type in a wafer id, I get:

```
Error in xi[[j]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I know from these posts:

[R shiny ERROR: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240434/r-shiny-error-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable)

[Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable)

That i am probabaly trying to subset an R base function without defining the variable name...but i feel stupid, Ive been staring at it for a day and cant see it. Maybe my whole code is a bad way to query SQL by shiny? Any help appreciated.

Ah dam, ok..if i change this:

```
wq <- reactive({ rbind(wq, query( a() )) })
```

to this:

```
wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })
```

Then I get an output. So im sorry, I guess my question changes to how to then populate a df with each additional click of the action button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your final object in a list you define as:

```
wq<- reactiveValues()
....
isolate()
```

I'm working on something similar with updating a model statement with reactively generated interaction terms. I had to use `reactiveValues()` and  `isolate()` to get it to work.  Joe Cheng has an example Gist.

Here's a link. Maybe it will help you. 
https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/eaedfed5095d37217fca

Best, 
NF

Comment: also-you might not be catching the NULL status of objects on startup. This is also shown in the Gist. Helpful tip I wanted to add. Anyways, Good luck!

Comment: Hi. Yes thanks I managed to find this eventually and all seems to work. Ive started to have problems recently though so I will post a separate question. Cheers. Pete

Comment: Cool beans. Keep on keeping on. We all struggle with R together. --NF