# store input as numeric value to generate three tables in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to create a large table to create some tables after that table in a Shiny app.

This is a part of my `server.R`:

```
function(input, output) {
    output$year <- renderText(input$year)

    ################################
    # CONFLICTING PART OF THE CODE
    year <- reactive({
      as.character(input$year)
    })

    matrix = tbl_df(dbReadTable(rca_matrices_db, reactive(paste0("table_",year))))
    ################################

    my_table = matrix %>% ... BLA BLA BLA

    output$more_than_10 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
      mytable %>% select(X1,X2) %>% filter(X1 > 10)
    }))

    output$less_than_10 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
      mytable %>% select(X1,X2) %>% filter(X1 < 10)
    }))    
  }
)
```

And the `year` comes from this part of `ui.R`

```
sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('year', 'Year', c("Select year",1999:2015), selected = 1999)
  )
```

If I replace, in the conflicting part of `server.R`, the `year` variable for

```
year <- 2000
```

then it works

any ideas?

Comment: hi try to use `year()` instead of `year` in `paste0...`

Comment: hi, thanks, I tried and the problem persists :S
its complicated because I want to add more user selectable parameters

Comment: maybe this will help there is a reactive query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446500/acessing-sql-database-using-shiny-with-reactive-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
    matrix = tbl_df(dbReadTable(rca_matrices_db, reactive(paste0("table_",year))))
```

is not reactive. It will not update whenever the reactive year changes. Also, as already pointed out in the comments, to call the value of the reactive `year`, you need to use `year()`. So you need to make my_table a reactive too, maybe as follows:

```
my_table <- reactive({ 
    my_matrix = tbl_df(dbReadTable(rca_matrices_db, reactive(paste0("table_",year()))))
    my_table = my_matrix %>% ... BLA BLA BLA
    return (my_table)
})
```

Now, the value of `my_table()` will update anytime `year()` changes, which changes anytime `input$year` changes. (Note, you could also directly put input$year here instead of making `year()` a separate reactive).

So you can now do:

```
output$more_than_10 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
  mytable() %>% select(X1,X2) %>% filter(X1 > 10)
}))
```

and this will update anytime the reactive `mytable()` changes, which as we just noticed changes as `input$year' changes. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks !! that unlocked creating a general table dynamically, now I cannot create smaller tables from that because of error `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character', and that's a new question

Comment: Could you post that as a new question on Stack Overflow? I can take a look at it when I'm home, if no one else has.

Comment: thanks a lot !! I already did ... so now I'll start posting replies to pure R questions, that is what I do know, the question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619547/shiny-dynamic-table-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-chara